# laravel eloquent forceDelete database query equivalent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I need to change my migration files because currently it's using model but I've read that we should not be using models inside migration files.

I have an eloquent code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use App\MyModel;

class AddRelationshipIdToMyModel extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        MyModel::query()->forceDelete();
        Schema::table('my_model', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('my_model_id')->constrained();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('my_model', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['my_model_id']);
        });
    }
}
```

I need to refactor this to not use model 'MyModel' but I don't know the equivalent for this in db query

Comment: It doesn't feel like there is enough information here for us to fully help you.

What does your full migration look like now and why do you feel you need to change it?

Comment: it would be a `delete` query, not sure what else needs to be explained ... you could truncate as well

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to Truncate the table before running the migration.
If I'm right then you need to use `DB::table()` and `truncate()` function.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use App\MyModel;

class AddRelationshipIdToMyModel extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        \DB::table('my_model')->truncate();
        Schema::table('my_model', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('my_model_id')->constrained();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('my_model', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['my_model_id']);
        });
    }
}
```